# External APFS drive won't mount - invalid o_subtype

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, apfs

Having the unfortunate experience of a potentially corrupted USB drive that won't mount:

```
/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +4.0 TB     disk3
                                 Physical Store disk2s2
   1:                APFS Volume Hello                     729.9 GB   disk3s1
```

**sudo fsck_apfs -l -n /dev/disk3** returns

```
** Checking the container superblock.
** Checking the space manager.
** Checking the space manager free queue trees.
** Checking the object map.
** Checking volume.
** Checking the APFS volume superblock.
** The volume Cam was formatted by diskmanagementd (945.220.38) and last modified by apfs_kext (945.220.38).
error: (oid 0x404b9a) om: btn: invalid o_subtype (15)
** Checking the object map.
   Object map is invalid.
** The volume /dev/disk3 could not be verified completely.
```

I've tried the `apfs-inspect` tool from https://github.com/jivanpal/apfs-tools
**sudo ./apfs-inspect /dev/disk3** >> https://pastebin.com/1fkPTJKY

```
Reading the Ephemeral objects used by this checkpoint ... OK.
Validating the Ephemeral objects ... FAILED.
An Ephemeral object used by this checkpoint is malformed. Going back to look at the previous checkpoint instead.
END: Handling of this case has not yet been implemented.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This drive was actually backed up on backblaze but unfortunately the data was removed due to their 30 day retention policy we weren't aware of.

Comment: They would have emailed you with a Missing Disk report at 14 days, by default.

Comment: Unfortunately it went to the client email where everything has been closed for weeks due to corona

Comment: Ah, OK. You might want to investigate their B2 storage for longer-term; I've not used it myself so idk the details. Wish you luck on this drive, I'm not good with APFS, but there are several here who are. All the best.

Comment: Thank you, this is very devastating as we did have a backup in place and it took some convincing to get the client to sign up for backblaze :(

Comment: If you get no expert advice in a reasonable time-frame, I've had success with Paragon's Hard Disk Manager on APFS drives with errors - but I haven't really had to test it out on anything 'hard'

Comment: OK I will keep it in mind thank you! Usually I reach for disk warrior but sadly it doesn't support APFS yet